# Devise asks authentication for Ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am working on a Rails 3 app which has devise as authentication. What I am trying to accomplish is pretty simple. I am updating an object on click of an attribute so here is my AJAX call:

```
$.post('/users/' + userId + '.json', user, function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){});
```

And in response to above call, I get an HTTP authentication dialog from the browser. I am wondering what might be the case? Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: need a bit more here m8 we can help we can't do magic or telepathy. what dialog, and what does the dialog say ?

Answer (score 2):

By default Devise requires you to provide a password whenever you try to update a user so based on your description I am assuming this is the cause of your problem.  There is a [devise wiki page that tells you how to change this behavior](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password).  Another option would be to write your own controller to handle updates to your user model outside of devise.  If you do disable the password requirement I would encourage you to enable some level of authorization to prevent everyone from being able to update user models. [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) is a simple and easy authorization gem that could help.